# Executing a hook after creating a subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I use plugin WooCommerce Subscribtion. I need run this code after create subscription
I need change order status to completed after payment and create subscription

```
function custom_autocomplete_order($order_id)
{

if($order_id) {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $order->update_status('completed');
}
} 
 add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'custom_autocomplete_order' );
```

Comment: Do you want it to execute earlier in the queue? Then you can lower the priority or register earlier. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/